# "Modules not assigned" versus "Not assigned Modules"

Tags: adjectives

I am developing an application, and there has to be a list of available modules, i.e. **modules that have not been assigned yet**. I am not sure what is the the right way to say it. My options:

- Not assigned modules
- Modules not assigned

I would rationally say that it should be "Not assigned modules", since the "not assigned" works as an adjective and therefore makes sense that it is placed first... but the other option somehow sounds more natural to my non-native speaker ears.

Which one is right? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a bit of a curve-ball, what about **Unassigned Modules**?

Comment: Sounds well. But among my options, which one is gramatically correct?

Comment: @bgusach Of the two, Modules not assigned sounds more correct.